# Invalid Formula on Excel Power Pivot Measure (CONCATENATEX)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have been using a formula to display text in a excel power pivot table, copied below:

```
=CONCATENATEX(TableX, [field_x])
```

This works for all my fields so far, however, I have just tried to use it in a cell and it is coming back as an invalid formula.

I have used this exact field in a separate table where it has less rows. I think that the amount of rows could be causing the problem as I think there is a character limit.

Is there any way around this problem? I need to display the information as a table, however by using power pivot there is no formula that occupies the formula bar which makes it more visible.

I have tried to research this problem but can't seem to find any definitive answer.

Comment: You can't use CONCATENATEX in a cell. It's DAX not an Excel function. You'd use TEXTJOIN in a cell.